# このままで: translation

Tags: expressions

Translating songs to improve my Japanese, I have quite often come across the expression:

このままで

The phrase should mean "in this condition", kono = this, mama = condition, state (shinjitai 侭 or kyūjitai 儘), de = in (postposition). In certain contexts, as in 此の侭でいいんだよ from Stereopony's 涙の向こう (namida no mukō), it is possible to directly use that translation, i.e. "This way it's fine". In other contexts, however, as for example in the refrain of いかないで (here's [song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9o4jfHX6rE&feature=youtube_gdata_player) and [lyrics](http://www.666ccc.com/lrc/5620/234298.htm), where as far as I know "iteta" should be "naiteta"), the given translation doesn't quite fit, as translating the refrain's last few phrases as "Don't go, this way" makes the expression disconnected from the neighbouring "ikanaide". So I am not sure what it means there and how to translate it. I interpreted it as something like "stay with me". What do you recommend?

Comment: Welcome to Japanese Language SE site. Can you provide your attempt at translation or explain the difficulties in detail? Translation questions without a genuine attempt are off-topic here.

Comment: "Don't go away, Stay with me". Because it should mean "in this condition", but it doesn'nt quite fit in here, so I tried some "phantasy", and I never like such improvising, so I came here :).

Comment: please edit your question and add that information. All the relevant information should be in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The このままで in このままでいいんだよ。 modifies the いい adverbially, meaning "It's okay to be just the way you are / just the way we are / It's okay to let it just the way it is", whereas the このままで in いかないで。このままで。 means このままでいてください or このままでいさせてください。(≒ Please stay where you are. / Please stay just as you are / Let us be just the way we are), いてください/いさせてください being left unsaid/implied.

このままで is written in Hiragana in modern Japanese.

Comment: the meaning of ~ままで are as it is, isn' t? you can replace the ~ with sono or kono